# Groovy script in soapui is not getting executed from testrunner

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I have the below mentioned groovy script in soapui where it

```
def date=new Date()
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory){ date = date.plus(10.minutes) }
def dateString = date.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UST'))
return dateString
```

From the request body i am calling this script as shown below,

```
{
  "name": "ABCD",
  "tempname": "XYZ",
  "starttime": "${StartTime#result}"
}
```

But it runs fine when i run it from console, but when i use TestRunner script is not getting executed.
Kindly let me know how to make a script run from testrunner which is same as running from cmd line.

Comment: What do you mean by `console`?

Comment: Hi Rao, Running from console means,  running my test steps by clicking green color run button.

Comment: From with in soapui tool?

Comment: Basavaraj, can you check the solution to see if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used in the way you mentioned, not sure of the issue. However, you could do something like below overcome the issue.

1.Make below change in the groovy script.

**From:**

```
return dateString
```

**To:**

```
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('START_DATE_TIME', dateString)
```

2.In the *Rest request test step*, change request
**From:**

```
{
  "name": "ABCD",
  "tempname": "XYZ",
  "starttime": "${StartTime#result}"
}
```

**To:**

```
{
  "name": "ABCD",
  "tempname": "XYZ",
  "starttime": "${#TestCase#START_DATE_TIME}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rao, after few small changes for my project specific it worked.